# Okta: Browser requests to the token endpoint must use Proof Key for Code Exchange

Tags: okta, okta-api, pkce, okta-signin-widget

I implemented the okta in our app. I am able to get the token in postman but not in browser.
the /token is failing with Browser requests to the token endpoint must use Proof Key for Code Exchange.

```
this.oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
```

But I am setting pkce:true in my config. But still seeing this error. Tried all the options, but still seeing the error.